# Getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked: when using jqgrid

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a page using jqgrid for the for the first time. I am using a simple example I found:
index.php

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: 'http://localhost/jqgrid/example.php',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["First Name", "Last Name", "Equipment Borrowed", "Service Tag", "Reason Borrowed", "Date Taken", "Expected Return Date", "Comments", "ID"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "FName",sortable: false },
            { name: "LName"},
            { name: "Eqpmnt_Brwd", align: "center"},
            { name: "Service_Tag", align: "right",sortable: false },
            { name: "Brwd_Rsn", align: "right", sortable: false },
            { name: "Date_Taken"},
            { name: "Exp_Return"},
            { name: "Comments", sortable: false },
            { name: "id"}
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 5,
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        sortname: "invid",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true, 
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: '500',
        loadonce: true,
        caption: "Alan's Grid"
    }); 
 }); 
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

example.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//database setting
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='***';
$dbpassword='***';
$database='inventory_form';
$page = $_GET['page'];
// get the requested page
$limit = $_GET['rows'];
// get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$sidx = $_GET['sidx'];
// get index row - i.e. user click to sort
$sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction if(!$sidx)
$sidx =1;
// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error conecting to db.");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Inventory");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];
if( $count > 0 ) {
$total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
}
else {
$total_pages = 0;
}
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Inventory ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());
$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id];
$responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[FName],$row[LName],$row[Eqpmnt_Brwd],$row[Service_Tag],$row[Brwd_Rsn],$row[Date_Taken],$row[Exp_Return],$row[Comments],$row[id]);

$i++;
}
echo json_encode($responce);
?>
```

I get only the column headers on my index.php page and looking at the java console I notice only one warning

```
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/jqgrid/example.php?_search=false&nd=1424558292246&rows=5&page=1&sidx=invid&sord=desc. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
http://localhost/jqgrid/example.php?_search=false&nd=1424558292246&rows=5&page=1&sidx=invid&sord=desc
Line 0
```

Reading up on CORS I set my Apache development server to  a2enmod headers but still get the error message. And I also tried the php command header(etc...) but also no good. I would prefer a client side solution if possible. Also I know I should be using PDO but I couldnt find an example. Even the jqgrid site example doesnt use PDO. Any advise on resolving this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of an origin
Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages.

> http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html    Success
>   http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html     Success
>   https://store.company.com/secure.html    Failure   Different protocal
>   http://store.company.com:81/dir/etc.html        Failure Different Port 
>   http://news.company.com/dir/other.html   Failure   Different host

You might change domain using

```
document.domain = "yourdomain.com";
```

Simpler and safer than enabling cross origin access

Comment: Thanks I changed to  url: 'http://192.168.1.20/jqgrid/example.php',
and no more warning. However still am not getting anything other then the column headers on my index page. do you have any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show what response you are getting for this request

Comment: I get this error on the example.php page:Couldn t execute query.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Apparently MySql has a problem with this line $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Inventory ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; I don't see it though.

Comment: Try to run this query by placing constants instead of variables, if it runs you will need to format this line correctly. Concatenating variables using dot operator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put   `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://datasource.com");` in the server NOT the client.
Example
https://origin.com/ is where you have jqgrid
https://datasource.com is where you want to get the data.
The php file in datasource will start with

```
<?php    
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://origin.com");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```